# How to multiple inner join same table but which different foreign keys, if its even possible?

Tags: php, mysql, reference, foreign-keys

I have a table with double foreign key reference to `gebruikersid` and now I'm kind of in a mess. First of all a "gebruiker" is a "user" in dutch, to avoid miscommunications.

The query I'm using now is:

```
$uploadeditems = "
                SELECT *
                FROM file f
                    INNER JOIN gebruikers g on f.empid = g.gebruikersid
                WHERE g.gebruikersid = ".$GET['employeeid']."
                ";
```

But what I actually would need to make is this something like this:

```
        $uploadeditems = "
                        SELECT *
                        FROM file f
                            INNER JOIN gebruikers on f.empid = gebruikers.gebruikersid as 'gebruikers.employee'
                            INNER JOIN gebruikers on f.gebruikersid = gebruikers.gebruikersid as 'gebruikers.uploader'
                        WHERE gebruikers.employee= ".$GET['employeeid']."
                        ";
```

Short about the code so you get my point:

Table FILE has `gebruikersid`, who is the uploader of the file and `empid`, the one on whose this file has to be linked. (both FK of gebruiker.gebruikersid).

So for instance I have in my database:

```
fileid  filename    filesize    filepath           custid   empid   gebruikersid    filedescription

228     Test.         60    files/employees/113/    NULL     113    70
```

So what I'm basically am trying is to have two references:

When I'm inner joining by `f.empid` I want to be able to return the `username` of the `f.empid & gebruiker.gebruikersid` reference, and with the same time I want to be able to return the `username` of the `f.gebruikersid & gebruikers.gebruikersid` reference, so what I could have return would be like:

File list of `user X`:
`File A`, uploaded by `user Y`.
`File B`, uploaded by `user Z`.
and so on...

Now I get:
File list of `user X`:
`File A`, uploaded by `user X`.
`File B`, uploaded by `user X`.
even when it's all good in the database.

*EDIT* Since I had an employee table before (and now all employees are users) my code names are messed up, it might be a little harder sorry. need to figure this all out once I can move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you join to the same table more than once, than you need to use an alias for at least one of the instances.  Then you must use the alias to prefix all the fields you select from the tables.

For example:

```
SELECT f.*, employee.FIELD1 as e_FIELD1, uploader.FIELD1 as u_FIELD1 ...

FROM   file f

       INNER JOIN gebruikers as employee
       on f.empid = employee.gebruikersid

       INNER JOIN gebruikers as uploader
       on f.gebruikersid = uploader.gebruikersid

WHERE gebruikers.employee= ".$GET['employeeid']."
```

Comment: The problem with that is that you will have duplicate field names.  You will have to alias fields to make them unique. I'll update my answer as an example.

Comment: Yes, it works! employee.*, and uploader.* seems to do it too. Damn, thanks alot, needed this! (accept possible in 1 minute)

Comment: Or maybe not.. Anyway thanks, this I need to go further with.

Comment: You can actually run the query with SELECT *, but I wouldn't recommend it because of the duplicated field names.

Answer (score 1):

I am agreed with the answer above, but you shoud replace gebruikers by g1 and g2 in each join.
And for me, it would be better to replace inner join by outer join, because if the empid could be null in your table, this piece of script will return nothing.

Comment: Good point.  I did change my aliases in my answer to something more meaningful.  g1 and g2 wasn't too descriptive.

Comment: I tested it well, so far so good. Using inner join still. Yes, returning NULl empids is good, I'm using 1 file table: if custid is set, then the customer has the list showed, if empid, then the user, if none of them both, than its a general document storage